# Stop TabItem children from triggering the parent's events

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

It is very strange that the content from TabItem should be able to fire events on TabItem.  I try to animate my TabItem when hover-in and hover-out, this works fine but the event is also firing on children hover-in and children hover-out, which as you can imageing is not very good:

```
<!-- TABCONTROL -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid Name="grdTab" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="20" MinWidth="80">
                    ...                       
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                     
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GlowOut}"></BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GlowIn}"></BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I stop the hover event from firing on children's hover events too?

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent's hover event `e.Handled` to `true`.